# MySQL str_to_date not converting dates properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following SQL (using MySQL 5.6.25 Community) to create a new table for banking information, and then load it from a CSV file; however, when I do, the "posted_date" field is set to NULL:

```
CREATE TABLE
IF NOT EXISTS account
(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
post_date DATE,
reference_num DECIMAL(24,0),
payee TEXT,
address TEXT,
amount DECIMAL(30,2));

LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE '/Users/tkessler/Data/banking.csv'
INTO TABLE account
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(post_date, reference_num, payee, address, amount)
SET
    post_date = str_to_date(post_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
    reference_num = cast(substring(reference_num,1,char_length(reference_num)) as DECIMAL(24,0)),
    payee = substring(payee, 2, char_length(payee)-2),
    address = substring(address,2,char_length(address)-2),
    amount = cast(substring(amount,1,char_length(amount)-2) as DECIMAL(30,2));
```

A few example lines of the data are the following:

```
04/15/2015,24393985105217960500072,"Company 1","Sacramento CA",-68.25
04/14/2015,24493985103247937700049,"Company 2","San Francisco CA",-10.00
04/14/2015,24592165103050851117121,"Company 3","Web Order",-24.99
04/13/2015,24792165102060610562563,"Company 4","Sacramento CA",-3.58
04/13/2015,24826385102370499124382,"Company 5","Sacramento CA",-29.81
```

When I run the SQL, I get the post_date set to NULL, but if I change the post_date data type to "text" then it does display a properly formatted date string from the str_to_date() function (e.g., '2015-04-15' from the first example data line here).

The kicker then is that if I use a static date string like '01/21/2000' instead of the 'post_date' variable in the str_to_date() function, along with the post_date data type being 'date,' then it works no problem and all imported entries get '2000-01-21' in the post_date field (formatted as the desired date data type).

I'm puzzled here, because a static date string converts and is implemented properly, but even though the dynamic date variable appears to convert to a properly formatted date entry by way of the str_to_date() function, MySQL is not recognizing it as a date, and is passing in NULL.

I've tried using the substring() function to remove any possible invisible leading or trailing characters from the date string being converted, but nothing is working. As far as I can tell, the input date is just basic text in the same format as the static date string, with nothing special to it that could be causing this problem.

Comment: how is the format? in your csv file you say it is 04/15/2015 but when the field is text you get 2015-04-15 ?

Comment: @fthiella, its converted from the format MM/DD/YYYY in the CSV file to YYYY-MM-DD by the str_to_date() function, which is the format that the "date" data type should accept.

Comment: MySQL tries to implicitly convert dates before you apply the str_to_date function, when you call this function `str_to_date(post_date, '%m/%d/%Y')` post_date is not a string but it's a date already, and it's null already, so it cannot be converted. That explains why only the date field is affected, but Alexey's solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to postprocess a field, you should use a temporary variable, like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE '/Users/tkessler/Data/banking.csv'
INTO TABLE account
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@post_date, reference_num, payee, address, amount)
SET
    post_date = str_to_date(@post_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
```

Comment: Ah! Its the simple oversights. Thanks! That fixes it. Odd it only seems to affect this one field, as opposed to the others.